# Inventory Management System

Tags: python, database, django, orm

I'm trying to learn Django by building an inventory management system, here's my final models.py.

I'm looking for feedback!

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models
from core.models import Department
from accounts.models import User


class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name='Description'
    )
    quantity_in_stock = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=0,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Quantity In Stock'
    )
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'items'
        verbose_name = 'Item'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Items'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('item-details', args=[self.id])
    
    def increase_stock_quantity(self, amount):
        self.quantity_in_stock += amount
        self.save()

    def decrease_stock_quantity(self, amount):
        if amount > self.quantity_in_stock:
            raise ValueError('The Amount is Larger Than the Quantity in Stock')
        self.quantity_in_stock -= amount
        self.save()
        

class PurchaseEntry(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Item'
    )
    unit_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Unit Price'
    )
    purchased_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=1,
        verbose_name='Purchased Quantity'
    )
    purchase_date = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Purchase Date'
    )
    supplier = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        verbose_name='Supplier'
    )
    entry_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Entry Number'
    )
    entry_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Entry Date'
    )
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'purchase_entries'
        ordering = ['-entry_date']
        verbose_name = 'Purchase Entry'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Purchase Entries'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.entry_date} - {self.item.description}'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.item.increase_stock_quantity(self.purchased_quantity)
        super(PurchaseEntry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_total_price(self):
        return self.unit_price * self.purchased_quantity

class IssuedItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='issued_items',
        verbose_name='Item'
    )
    recipient_employee = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='issued_items',
        verbose_name='Recipient Employee'
    )
    recipient_department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='issued_items',
        verbose_name='Recipient Department'
    )
    issue_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=1,
        verbose_name='Issue Quantity'
    )
    issue_reason = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        verbose_name='Issue Reason'
    )
    issue_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Issue Date'
    )
    exit_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Exit Number'
    )
    notes = models.TextField(
        default='',
        verbose_name='Notes'
    )
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'issued_items'
        verbose_name = 'Issued Item'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Issued Items'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.issuance_date} - {self.item.description} - {self.recipient}'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.issued_quantity > self.item.quantity_in_stock:
            raise ValidationError('Issued Quantity Exceeds Available Quantity')
        self.item.decrease_stock_quantity(self.issued_quantity)
        super(IssuedItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ReturnedItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='returned_items',
        verbose_name='Item'
    )
    return_reason = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Reason for Return'
    )
    return_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=1,
        verbose_name='Return Quantity'
    )
    return_date = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Return Date'
    )
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'returned_items'
        verbose_name = 'Returned Item'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Returned Items'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.item.description} - {self.return_date} - {self.quantity_returned} - {self.return_reason}'
```

Answer (score 2):

> looking for some feedback

We have some nouns, here.
I don't see any verbs.
Certainly there is no
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).
It's unclear what entrypoint someone
would use to exercise this codebase.

I imagine there is some business problem we wish to address.
The code has not yet made that apparent,
and no specification has been cited.
A unit test would be a very good way of demonstrating
how we expect to interact with the datastore,
and what results we might hope to get back from it.

Answer (score 2):

### Avoid premature optimization

```
quantity_in_stock = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(...)
purchased_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(...)
issue_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(...)
return_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(...)
```

Don't shrink these fields to `PositiveSmall` unless you somehow have infrastructure that necessitates it.

Here I'd say it's not only unnecessary but even counterproductive to limit your inventory to `PositiveSmall`:

1. `Positive` precludes negative inventory, which does happen in practice
2. `Small` precludes organizations with 32,768+ inventory

---

### Use consistent naming

The Issue and Return models are named `IssuedItem` and `ReturnedItem`, but the Purchase model is named `PurchaseEntry`. Unless there is a good reason I'm missing, I'd use `PurchasedItem` for consistency.

---

### Avoid redundant naming

Many of the fields are prefixed with the model name. Remove the prefixes to reduce verbosity:

- `Item.quantity_in_stock` -> `Item.quantity`
- `PurchasedItem.purchase_quantity` -> `PurchasedItem.quantity`
- `PurchasedItem.purchase_date` -> `PurchasedItem.date`
- `IssuedItem.issue_reason` -> `IssuedItem.reason`
- `IssuedItem.issue_quantity` -> `IssuedItem.quantity`
- `IssuedItem.issue_date` -> `IssuedItem.date`
- `ReturnedItem.return_reason` -> `ReturnedItem.reason`
- `ReturnedItem.return_quantity` -> `ReturnedItem.quantity`
- `ReturnedItem.return_date` -> `ReturnedItem.date`